# PowerShell script for mail content download

Tags: excel, powershell, outlook

I need to automate this task using PowerShell:

1. open the Outlook
2. filter mail with respective subject
3. download those attachments of that mail
4. copy that attachment to Excel sheet

Please give idea.

Comment: Open your preferred editor and start typing. Both Outlook and Excel expose COM objects that can be used from PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

This is to give you some idea.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$inbox_mails = $Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder('olFolderInbox').Items
foreach ($mail in $inbox_mails){
    Write-Host $mail.Subject
}
```

Expand on this to get the desired mail and download the attachment.If an excel file is shared as attachment, the same can be saved as such.

Comment: Hi, Many thanks. Start-Process Outlook.exe | Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Serach-Mailbox -identity abcd@outlook.com -SerachQuery 'subject:"eminem*"' | i believe these commands for .. to start the outlook .. keeping the download space unlimited .. seraching mail box of the user .. then searching the sub of eminem .. now please help me wthr my understanding is correct .. if yes , then how to develop to search in one particular folder and download the attachment and save it in desired location .. many thanks ! bare me if im wrong somewhere above. im just a rookie :)